# Mutual subscriptions of subscriptions of an Person SQL Query

Tags: sql, oracle

In my previous question, I asked how to write a cypher query for mutual subscriptions of subscriptions of a person. I got helped and I am grateful but now I need the same query in SQL syntax. My first thought was that I need to write a recursive query for this. But I am not sure and hence need some guidance on whether this would be right or there's some other way.

my model in ORACLE RDBMS is as follow:

```
Person(PersonID, Age, Gender)

Relationship(FromPersonID, ToPersonID)
```

Imagine I am the Person who wants to discover, which mutual subscriptions, my subscriptions have i.e (me---> my Subscriptions ---> mutual subscriptions of my subscriptions).

Need some more guidance on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select prs1.PersonID fromPersonID, prs1.Age fromAge, prs1.Gender fromGender
     , prs2.PersonID toPersonID, prs1.Age toAge, prs1.Gender toGender
  from Person prs1
     , Person prs2
     , Relationship rlsp
 where prs1.PersonId = rlsp.fromPersonID
   and prs2.PersonId = rlsp.toPersonID
```